# Spacings sizes in Vuetify Playground

Tags: material-design, vuetify.js, margins

There is no 24px standard in the Vuetify>Spacings>Playground specifically for Margins.

Sizes comes with: 0,1,2,3,4,5 if converted to pixels it is 0,8,16,32,48

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/spacing#spacing

I expect to have a 24px in the vuetify standards Spacings > Playground.

QUESTION: Is it ideal to predefine/entirely change the value of one the sizes?

Comment: We discussed this a while ago, thanks for reminding me: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been updated in Vuetify version 2.0.5. It is ma-6 that gives you 24px

Comment: Thank you, we needed the ma-3 and pa-3 which is the 12px.. all the things you added are really great! 

why 3? because we need 12px to have a total corners of 24px =)